# How to implement Infinite scrolling to SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, master-page, search-results, custom-masterpage

For example:

The search page in SharePoint takes me a long period of time for loading results (what if I got more than 1 million results) so I need to display only 20-30 results first and then for the next 20-30 results.

How can I implement the Infinite scrolling to that search layout?

Comment: Is it infinite scrolling or Paging ?

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri, isn't infinite scrolling just a fancy way of doing Ajax paging? :)

Comment: @RobertLindgren, Is it? I never heard of that term :)

Comment: I think it is when you automatically loads in more items when you are approaching the bottom of the page

Comment: Here are some samples:

http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/
http://desandro.github.io/masonry/demos/infinite-scroll.html